# Treat double loop from sql query?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm currently learning php/mysql, and I have a project.

I have 3 main SQL tables:

- animations contains names, dates, adresses, etc
- animateurs ('workers') is a list of people with many data
- crosstable is a many-to-many relationship between the two other tables. Each line contains an "animationId", an "animateurId" and a status (is he/she interested, free, or not?).

[many-to-many SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSGGS.png)

I'm trying to make a web table showing all the animations, with one columns containing the animators. I would like to sort them based on their status. This is what I managed to do so far:

[my results table atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bZRM.png)

(I'm still pretty proud, having started learning php and SQL 1 month ago and not being a programmer... but whatever).

At first, I tried to run multiple while loops with $rowDispos but it doesn't seem to reset.
I think I might run one loop and create different arrays for the status of each person for each animation but I'm not sure how to do this.

My objective is to have another list of people below "Disponibles :", labeled "If necessary :".

At some point, I'll need to gather data for all the people participating to one event (to send them an email for example).

Above all I'm not sure what would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Thank you!

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM animations  LEFT JOIN crosstable ON animations.idAnimation = crosstable.idAnimation LEFT JOIN animateurs ON crosstable.idAnimateur = animateurs.idAnimateur";
    $res = $pdo->query($sql);
    if ($res->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Nom de l'animation</th>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>Horaire</th>";
        echo "<th>Nombre d'animateurs</th>";
        echo "<th>Animateurs disponibles</th>";
        echo "<th>Ma disponibilité</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while ($row = $res->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['animationNom']."</td>";
            //Date
            $timeStamp=strtotime($row['dateAnim']);
            $numJourAnim=date("w", $timeStamp);
            $jourAnim=$jour[$numJourAnim];
            echo "<td>" . $jourAnim . "</br>" . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['dateAnim'])) ."</td>";
            //Heures
            echo "<td>de ".substr($row['heureDebut'], 0, 5)."<br/>à " . substr($row['heureFin'], 0, 5)."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['nombreAnim']."</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            $req = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM animateurs JOIN crosstable ON animateurs.idAnimateur = crosstable.idAnimateur WHERE idAnimation = :idAnimation");
            //echo $row['idAnimation'];
            $req->bindParam(':idAnimation', $row['idAnimation']);
            $req->execute();
            echo "Disponibles :<br/>";

            while ($rowDispos = $req->fetch()) {

              if ($rowDispos['disponibilite']=="disponible") {
                echo $rowDispos['prenom']. " " .$rowDispos['nom'] . "<br/>";
              }
            }
            
            echo "<td>".'<input type="radio" id="disponibilite" name="disponibilite_id' . $row['idAnimation'] . '" value="disponible">Intéressé<br/>'.
                        '<input type="radio" id="disponibilite" name="disponibilite_id' . $row['idAnimation'] . '" value="non">Non disponible<br/>'.
                        '<input type="radio" id="disponibilite" name="disponibilite_id' . $row['idAnimation'] . '" value="siBesoin">Si nécessaire<br/>'.
            "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        unset($res);
    }
    else {
        echo "No matching records are found.";
    }
```

```
idAnimateur prenom  nom email   gsm codePostal  naissance   statut  francais    anglais neerlandais tailleTShirt    asmoTShirt  idUser  
37  Wanda   Maximoff    wanda@gmail.com 1111111 7000    1983-04-09  independant 1   0   0   L   0   2   
36  Tony    Stark   tony@despunches.be  666 7000    2022-10-03  independant 1   1   1   L   0   1
```

[image: Animation DB]

To reexplain things:

I need a table with 1 line per animation (per event).
Each column contains data about that event (date, time, place,...).
One columns contains data about people for that event. They can be present, interested, or busy. I would like, in that column, to sort and list people between present, interested, and busy. This data is stored in crosstable, with the id's of the event, the people, and their "status" concerning that event (and probably other things later on).

I'll need (one step at a time, but it might be important) to send an email to all the people that are marked as "present" at an event.

Comment: Yes, you've achieved quite a lot in one month, you clearly have an aptitude for programming. You're even using prepared statements! Doing a query inside your `while ()` loop is not very efficient, better do everything in a query outside that loop. I could tell you how to do that for the `Disponibles` (available animators), but your question is about the "If necessary" column. Regretably, I don't don't understand what you mean by this. I cannot relate it to the database information you've given. Perhaps you should show more of your database tables?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but I'm still lost with big, complex SQL queries and how to treat them. I'll add some more information my post.

Comment: It's my fault, I had removed some parts of the code that didn't work... I tried this:
echo "If necessary :<br/>";
while ($rowDispos = $req->fetch()) {

              if ($rowDispos['disponibilite']=="siBesoin") {
                echo $rowDispos['prenom']. " " .$rowDispos['nom'] . "<br/>";
              }
            }

I had this AFTER the loop checking for "disponibles" people and of course it didn't work.

I added more comments in my original post, I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, let's stick with the query inside the `while ()` loop. You want the animateurs stored by their status. You currently have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM animateurs 
JOIN crosstable ON animateurs.idAnimateur = crosstable.idAnimateur 
WHERE idAnimation = :idAnimation
```

Currently you're only using 3 columns. In that case it's better to really name those columns:

```
SELECT 
  animateurs.disponibilite, 
  animateurs.prenom,
  animateurs.nom
FROM animateurs 
JOIN crosstable ON animateurs.idAnimateur = crosstable.idAnimateur 
WHERE crosstable.idAnimation = :idAnimation;
```

Note how I make clear, every time, in which table a column is located. It might not be needed now, but when queries become more complex it will prevent errors.

Now you could use three queries to get the three status groups:

```
SELECT 
  animateurs.disponibilite, 
  animateurs.prenom,
  animateurs.nom
FROM animateurs 
JOIN crosstable ON animateurs.idAnimateur = crosstable.idAnimateur 
WHERE crosstable.idAnimation = :idAnimation AND
      crosstable.disponibility = 'disponible';
```

And the same for the `'non'` and `'sieBesoin'` people. However, we like to do this in one query. I would keep it simple and use this:

```
SELECT 
  animateurs.disponibilite, 
  animateurs.prenom,
  animateurs.nom,
  crosstable.disponibility
FROM animateurs 
JOIN crosstable ON animateurs.idAnimateur = crosstable.idAnimateur 
WHERE crosstable.idAnimation = :idAnimation;
```

Now you can sort them in PHP:

```
$animateurGroups = [];
while ($rowDispos = $req->fetch()) {
    $disponibility = $rowDispos['disponibilite'];
    $animateurGroups[$disponibility][] = $rowDispos['prenom']. " " .$rowDispos['nom'];
}
```

And then you can display the three groups like so:

```
foreach ($animateurGroups as $disponibility => $animateurGroup) {
    echo "Disponibles: $disponibility<br/>";
    foreach ($animateurGroup as $animateur) {
        echo "$animateur<br>";
    }
}
```

Later you should try and get the query completely out of this `while ()` loop.

---

---

OK, I will try to put only a single query outside of the `while ()` loop. We'll follow the same strategy as before, but now we have to add in the information about the animations, keeping in mind that there can be animations without any animators.

I now notice that the main query you have already does this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM animations  
LEFT JOIN crosstable ON animations.idAnimation = crosstable.idAnimation 
LEFT JOIN animateurs ON crosstable.idAnimateur = animateurs.idAnimateur";
```

However, I always like to specify what I take from database, if only so that I can tell what is there, because I haven't got your database.

```
SELECT 
  animations.idAnimation,
  animations.animationNom,
  animations.dateAnim,
  animations.heureDebut,
  animations.heureFin,
  animateurs.disponibilite, 
  animateurs.prenom,
  animateurs.nom,
  crosstable.disponibility
FROM animations  
LEFT JOIN crosstable ON animations.idAnimation = crosstable.idAnimation 
LEFT JOIN animateurs ON crosstable.idAnimateur = animateurs.idAnimateur";
```

Now we need to sort these results in PHP:

```
$animations = [];
while ($rowDispos = $req->fetch()) {
    $idAnimation = $rowDispos['idAnimation'];
    if (!isset($animations[$idAnimation]) {
        $animations[$idAnimation] = ['animationNom' => $rowDispos['animationNom'],
                                     'dateAnim'     => $rowDispos['dateAnim'],
                                     'heureDebut'   => $rowDispos['heureDebut'],
                                     'heureFin'     => $rowDispos['heureFin']];
    }
    $disponibility = $rowDispos['disponibilite'];
    if (!is_null($disponibility)) {
        $animateurNom = $rowDispos['prenom']. " " .$rowDispos['nom'];
        $animations[$idAnimation]['animateurGroups'][$disponibility][] = $animateurNom;
    }
}
```

Note that I have no way to check this code myself, so I cannot guarantee it is correct.

Now that we have gathered everything in an array we can render the HTML table. This is a very much simplified version of that:

```
foreach ($animations as $idAnimation => $animation) {
    echo $animation['animationNom'] . '<br>';
    echo $animation['dateAnim'] . '<br>';
    echo $animation['heureDebut'] . '<br>';
    echo $animation['heureFin'] . '<br>';
    if (isset($animation['animateurGroups']) {
        foreach ($animation['animateurGroups'] as $disponibility => $animateurGroup) {
            echo "Disponibles: $disponibility<br/>";
            foreach ($animateurGroup as $animateur) {
                echo "$animateur<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This basically outputs everything on lines, not in a table, you I think you can see how you can turn this back into a table.

Storing everything in an array will work well for a limited number of animations. If you have thousands of them you should use [LIMIT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx) in your query.

Again, I must stress that I cannot properly test this code, and I know mistakes are quickly made. However, I think this should get you started.

Comment: Ok... Thank you, it's quite clear, and it works. Now I'm trying to do what you suggested: getting the query out of the while loop.

As far as I understand, I should end up with an array (events), with each row containing an array (my disponibility groups), with each row containing an array (my  workers).

And... I'm a bit lost. I don't think my problem is (yet) at the implementation part. I don't think I even see what I should do, in terms of query (one big join? multiple queries) and algorithm...

Comment: @Antoine I tried something to get you started, see the edited answer above.

Comment: I think that I finally understood between my last comment and your answer. I managed to write a code that seems to work, while not as clean as yours. 4D arrays is a bit too much!  I also have an error at the last foreach (with my code) that I don't understand. "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". Maybe a syntax error?
I don't know what is the policy of stackOverflow exactly. May I c/p my actual code for a verification, and if so, where?

Comment: @Antoine `foreach ()` requires an array as the argument. You can answer your own question if you want to show your code, and it does what was asked in the question.